# Mirroring parts of redux state in local database

Tags: database, redux, architecture, redux-thunk

I'm working on a simple app which state is managed using redux and redux-thunk. The app supports some basic CRUD operations about different classes  (e.g Items). The results of those CRUD operations should change part of the redux state (in order to display new information in the UI), but also be persistent against app restarts.

Which is the best pattern to fulfill those requirements?

**A -** Create two redux actions, one for just updating the local state of the app (e.g `AddItem`) and a second one using a thunk (e.g. `CreateItem`) in charge of updating the state of the app to loading, access the database asynchronously, dispatching `AddItem`, and toggling again the loading state

**B -** For each CRUD operation, update only the local state and mirroring it to the database whenever the lifecycle of the app ends.

I know option B would imply a lot of possible problems, but option A doesn't look very good for me, as long as it implies conceptually duplicating some actions. Which option is better? Is there any other approach I'm not considering?

Thaks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is use 3 actions: ACTION_NAME{REQUEST/RESPONSE/ERROR} (good example: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions). So your basic flow is:

execute thunk -> request is dispatched (change local state to loading) -> call BE API -> api finishes -> refresh local storage depending on success or error. You can write a custom action creator or middleware that will automatically dispatch REQUEST/RESPONSE/ERROR actions when you call a BE API (this is an excelent example: https://blog.logrocket.com/data-fetching-in-redux-apps-a-100-correct-approach-4d26e21750fc/).

The big problem with the B solution is if you have more than 1 user. Since changes are only saved on app end, user A will not see any of the user B changes until user B logs out. If that is not an issue then for saving the state I recommend something like: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With "refresh local storage depending on success or error" you mean updating the state with another action, right? Thus, that would be opton A, isn't?

Comment: Yes. I have used thath approach on multiple big projects and it is very clean and easy to debug, especially if you name your actions with REQUEST/RESPONSE/ERROR postfix.